# Search rows in list, where one field match any value out of the String Array

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to explain my question using below example.

I have one list created, which has fields like -- 
StudEmail,FirstName, LastName,Age,EligibilityMode

Now, 
I have one String Array list as below to validate the EligibilityMode column for all allowed values.

```
List<string> EligModes = new List<string> { "WithCertificate", "With Certificate", "WithoutCertificate","Without Certificate" };
```

How to get the list of rows out of my main list, where EligibilityMode doesn't have matching values in EligModes String Array List.

I tried doing this using Contains(),existvalue() and Any(), but not able to find the solution.

```
MainList.Where(c => (c.EligibilityMode.existvalue(EligModes))).ToList();
```

Any help on this?

EDIT:

I have tried below:

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1 = ds.Tables[0];
List<object> lst = dt1.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();

lst = lst.Where(c => !EligModes.Contains(c.EligibilityMode)).ToList();
```

But it is not identifying the column in c.EligibilityMode.

Also, I tried,

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1 = ds.Tables[0];
List<object> lst = dt1.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();

result = from m in lst
     where !EligModes.Any(val => lst.EligibilityMode.Contains(val))
     select m;
```

Here also the same problem with lst.EligibilityMode.

Please confirm that I am creating list from datatable is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives items from main list which have EligibilityMode value not listed in EligModes list:

```
MainList.Where(c => !EligModes.Contains(c.EligibilityMode)).ToList();
```

UPDATE: thus `MainList` is a list of data rows, converted to objects, you can't access any properties of data row (actually `EligibilityMode` property even don't exist here). Here is correct DataTable processing:

```
var rows = from r in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
           where !EligModes.Contains(r.Field<string>("EligibilityMode"))
           select r;
```

Or with method syntax:

```
var rows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
             .Where(r => !EligModes.Contains(r.Field<string>("EligibilityMode"));
```

You should learn [basics of Linq to DataSet querying](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I tried this : lst = lst.Where(c => !EligModes.Contains(c.EligibilityMode)).ToList(); but it shows syntax error red line under c.EligibilityMode. I am not sure why it is not identifying the Column name in the list. I have converted my datatable to list as :   DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                            dt1 = ds.Tables[0];
                            List<object> lst = dt1.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();

Comment: @MittalPatel is `c.EligibilityMode` a string?

Comment: Yes. Column type is string.I have again updated the question what I have tried. Please see there.

Comment: @MittalPatel no, it is not string. You even don't have this property, thus you selected list of objects from your data table

Answer (score 0):

Try this also (although haven't checked):

```
result = from m in MainList
           where !EligModes.Any(val => MainList.EligibilityMode.Contains(val))
           select m;
```

Answer (score 0):

it may work.
MainList.Where(c => EligModes.Contains(c.EligibilityMode)).ToList();